# Who could send me some ETH in rinkeby, thx

Tags: blockchain, ether, rinkeby

my address：0x4CD13B975e1c5AE675bCD038c9ad4BB6Ff2De627

thx!

Comment: Rinkeby has been deprecated, Goerli is now the only Ethereum testnet. You can get Goerli testETH reliably here (there's a limit but it's enough for testnet builds and you can get more every day) - https://goerlifaucet.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also good solutions is (with immediately sending): https://rinkebyfaucet.com/

Comment: i got it, thx my bro 

Answer (score 0):

Done.

TxHash -
`0x03f6508cd10dc3ee63e587e08743f0a5e7e0cb2106536863046e743141dd859a`

In future, if you want ETH on any testnet, use the chainlink faucet. https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

Comment: i got it, thx my bro 